# How to POST items to an Azure SQL Easy Table from Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to access an Azure SQL table that I have connected to an Azure App Service from within a local node.js app (not running on Azure).

I've made progress in terms of *querying* the table - I can get the full contents of any table I have connected to my App Service, and I can even apply odata filters on that data. For example:

```
var request = require("request");

request({
    method:'GET',
    url:"https://my-service.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem?$filter=complete eq true"
},(err,res,body)=>{
    console.log(body);
});
```

So **requesting** data from the table works just fine right now. However, following [this information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#TableOperations), I'm led to believe I can **post** new items to tables as well. I've tried that a number of ways and simply cannot find out how to add a new record to a table. Here's something I've tried:

```
request({
    method:'POST',
    url:"https://my-service.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem",
    json: true,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        text: 'I just posted this',
        date: new Date(),
        complete: false
    })
},(err,res,body)=>{
    console.log(body);
});
```

This gives me an 'invalid JSON' response.

So what's the correct way to do a POST request to **insert** an item to an Easy Table? I'd also like to know how to **update** a record as well with PATCH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391368/azure-mobile-service-forwarding-post-request-in-insert-script-of-table?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Using `request.post()` instead of `request({method:'POST',...})`

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{
    var p = request.parameters;
    require('request').post({
        uri : 'http://someURL/',
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body : item
    }, function(err, res, body){
        if (err)
        {
            request.respond(500, "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"); 
        }
        else
        {
            request.respond(200,"Success"); 
        }
    });
}
```